# NotificationCompat.Builder - Incompatibile types

Tags: android, notifications

I have a problem with `NotificationCompat.Builder`. For me the code below looks fine but the Android Studio says it is not. What could be the reason of such behavior?

```
NotificationCompat noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
   .setContentTitle("service")
   .setContentText("running")
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
   .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
   .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", pIntent)
   .build();
```

IDE error:

```
Incompatibile types.
Required: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
Found: android.app.Notification
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include android support library and import it

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Comment: i am not familiar with android studio .. but in eclipse this error may happen if the library is not attached properly

Answer (score 0):

I think now I get it. Somehow notification object must be of `android.app.Notification` type, not the `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`.

the solution is following:

```
 Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

Comment: Your answer seem to be incorrect. It should be `Notification.Builder noti ...` instead of `Notification noti ...`!