# How to create a notification in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a *simple* notification in android. The purpose is to show a small icon on top of the phone screen when something is happening. Then I can tap on the notification which will either start the app or brings it in the foreground.

For just testing purposes I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) hard-to-understand-and-not-simple example and also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679940/notificationcompat-builder-incompatibile-types) entry for the first error I get.

Anyway here is the code:

```
    Notification mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    int mId = 1001;
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

and here is what I am importing:

```
...
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
....
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
//import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

The current error is

```
Error:(117, 32) error: incompatible types
required: Notification
found:    Builder
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: "Anyway here is the code" -- The [docs appear to have it typed in correctly](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification), whereas your opening lines attempt to assign a `NotificationCompat.Builder` to a `Notification`.

Comment: Neither works. The only thing that changes is the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Notification mBuilder
```

with

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder
```

Since you are instantiating `new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)` you can't assign it to a `Notification` object

Comment: Error:(117, 32) error: incompatible types
required: android.app.Notification.Builder
found:    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: my bad you need `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Comment: Error:(117, 32) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
found:    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: you have to be consistent with the import. All the imports have to be from the same package `v4.app` or `v7.app`. Check in the documentation which suits your needs better

Comment: I do not see any 'v4' imports. `NotificationCompat` is v7: `import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;`

Comment: you posted this `Error:(117, 32) error: incompatible types required: android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder found: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98472/discussion-between-alex-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue following Udacity tutorial on Android and found out that I was missing a cast. You should  change your code to

```
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)
                            .setContentTitle(My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

You are using a NotificationCompat and you are assigning to a Notification

Comment: Weirdly, this solved my issue. But I don't understand why since .setContentText(..) and the other methods return a builder object, not a notification?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with answer from @Blackbelt, `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` is a subclass of `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` and its member functions like `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)` returns instances of `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` which cannot be casted to `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`. So, best practice would be:

```
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
.
.
.
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)
   .setContentTitle("My notification")
   .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet it would work for creating the notification in android

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

//build your notification here.
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1)
                                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                                .setAutoCancel(true); //notification will be removed when once you enter application.
```

Hope this helps you..

Cheers